# Where can I find documentation for PHP's escape_data() function?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to validate a submitted form using PHP. I'm a noob and working off of an example that uses escape_data() instead of mysql_real_escape_string(). Where can I find a thorough explanation for what escape_data() does (there's nothing in the PHP documentation)?

Here's the example code:

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
} else {
    $e = escape_data($_POST['email']);
}
```

Comment: if you are in learning phase use PDO or mysqli with prepared http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: That function must be defined in your code base somewhere. You could try grepping for it. You should try to move away from escaping though..

Comment: Do you think PDO is good to use for validating user-defined mathematical equations?

Comment: @T.Ato PDO is just used to connect to your database. You should validate in the PHP.

Comment: Ah, I meant prepared statements.

Comment: Prepared statements are in place of escaping. The driver handles the quoting of the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function `escape_data` in PHP. It must be a user defined function. Please refer the source from where you copied it.